# Is there a way to check matches from one spreadsheet to another? Vlookup? Index match?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to compare matches from one spreadsheet to another. Where I want to validate the data from the source on the "PT" matches the data from the source on the "BQ" tab, that each sort bin contains the same amount & exact match.
I'm trying to audit / check matches on the spreadsheet DC and BQ. Is there a way I can lookup if columns A, B, & C match on both spreadsheets?
VLOOKUP?
INDEX MATCH?

Answer (score 0):

Your sheet isn't open for editing. You may try with COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(BQ!A:A,A2,BQ!B:B,B2,BQ!C:C,C:C)
```

If the result is 1, it means there's an exact match; and you can use that result in an IF clause: =IF(COUNTIFS.....,"MATCH","DON'T MATCH"), for example